# Store database connection as separate Class - Java

Tags: java, class, jdbc, connection

Is it possible to store a database connection as a separate class, then call the database objects from a main code? ie;

```
public class main{
    public static void main{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.jdbc.driver");
            Database to = new Database(1,"SERVER1","DATABASE");
            Database from = new Database(2,"SERVER2","DATABASE");

            String QueryStr = String.format("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Id = %i", to.id)
            to.results = sql.executeQuery(QueryStr);

            while (to.results.next()) {
                String QueryStr = String.format("INSERT INTO Table (A,B) VALUES (%s,%s)",to.results.getString(1),to.results.getString(2));
                from.sql.executeQuery("QueryStr");
            }
            to.connection.close()
            from.connection.close()

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        { finally {
            if (to.connection != null)
                try {
                    to.connection.close();
                    } catch (SQLException x) {
                    }
            if (from.connection != null)
                try {
                    from.connection.close();
                    } catch (SQLException x) {
                    }

        }
    }

    public static class Database {
    public int id;
        public String server;
        public String database;
        public Connection connection;
        public ResultSet results;
        public Statement sql;

        public Database(int _id, String _server, String _database) {
            id = _id;
            server = _server;
            database = _database;
            String connectStr = String.format("jdbc:driver://SERVER=%s;port=6322;DATABASE=%s",server,database);
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr);
            sql = connection.createStatement;
        }
    }
}
```

I keep getting a "Connection object is closed" error when I call `to.results = sql.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE");` like the connection closes as soon as the Database is done initializing.

The reason I ask is I have multiple databases that are all about the same that I am dumping into a master database.  I thought it would be nice to setup a loop to go through each `from` database and insert into each `to` database using the same class.  Is this not possible?  `Database` will also contain more methods than shown as well.  I am pretty new to java, so hopefully this makes sense...

Also, my code is probably riddled with syntax errors as is, so try not to focus on that.

Comment: Without knowing what your code is actually doing, it's impossible to say. No clue where/how you open the connection, what `sql` is or how it interacts with the connection, etc.

Comment: I would recommend against using `String.format` to pass the parameters: that's how you're likely to be vulnerable to SQL injections. Use `PreparedStatement`s and set the parameters via its setters instead.

Comment: Dave, the connection is made (or should be) when I initialize the database with `Database to = new Database(...)`, `sql` is the databases `connection.createStatement`

Comment: A few more points... It would actually be easier to debug without the syntax errors (the to/from vars are clearly out of scope of the catch block). You may have cleaned up your example from actual code, but it's not easy to see what you may have cut out and moved around. Try to stick to the Java naming conventions too (camel-case, first letter lower case for variables and class names starting with upper case). As much as it's good to use objects in Java, it seems overkill here. You could have your from/to variables as local variables within your bigger method, in a more "procedural" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Connection object is closed* doesn't mean that the connection is closed, but that the object relative to the connection is closed (it could be a `Statement` or a `ResultSet`).

It's difficult to see from your example, since it has been trimmed/re-arranged, but it looks like you may be trying to use a `ResultSet` after having re-used its corresponding `Statement`. See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
>   at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
>   interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
>   by different Statement objects. **All execution methods in the Statement
>   interface implicitly close a statment's current ResultSet object if an
>   open one exists.**

Answer (score 0):

In your example, it may be because autoCommit is set to true by default.  You can override this on the java.sql.Connection class.  Better yet is to use a transaction framework if you're updating multiple tables.